# Constructing and plotting a special periodic function

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, periodic-function

I need to program and plot the following special function in Mathematica 12.0:

$$
a_{1}(t)= \sum_{n\geq 1} \beta_{n}(t), 
$$ 
such that, for every $ n \geq 1 $ 
$$ 
\beta_{n}(t)= \displaystyle \sum_{i \in P_{n}} H(n^{2}(t-i)),
$$
with $ P_{n}=3^{n}(2\mathbb{Z}+1) $ and $ H \in C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}) $ with support in $ (\frac{-1}{2},\frac{1}{2}) $ such that 
$$  
H \geq 0 , \quad H(0)=1 \quad \text{and} \quad \int_{\frac{-1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} H(s) ds =1 .  
$$

This special function is an example of an oscillatory function which is of class C infinity, but not bounded.

Comment: where does $P_n$ comes into play? I do not see it. And have you tried anything you could share?

Comment: $P_n$ plays in the second sum of $\beta_n$

Comment: To begin, I think, I should define first a function $H$ that satisfies the assumptions: for example $H(t)=(1-t)\xi_{(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})}$, where $\xi$ is the indicator function. After that, we can define $P_n$ as a function of integer numbers. Then, we can sum twice in $i$ and $n$ together ?!

Comment: We can't simply compute an infinite sum. Although Mathematica has NSum capable of such things in principle, it won't work well with an infinite series consisting of sporadically appearing non-zeros. I'd write a function that, instead of blindly iterating over a wide range of values, directly finds and adds the small finite number of nonzero terms. As a first step, you can start with defining beta[n_, t_] this way. Also, regarding H, shouldn't it be smooth? It seems your example definition has discontinuities at -1/2 and 1/2.

Comment: On the other hand, if you don't care about speed or being super precise at every possible point, summing twice over a small finite range of i and n is perfectly fine.

Comment: Of course, as you said the example of the function $H$ that I gave is not smooth as required. A typical example is some kind of Mollifier functions. $\varphi(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-1/(1/2-|x|^2)}/I_n& \text{ if } |x| < 1/2 \\
                 0& \text{ if } |x|\geq 1/2
                 \end{cases}$                                                                                                 Thank you very much for your interesting comments.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

Two candidate $H$ functions I can think of are

$H(s)=\frac{1}{1+0.01s^2}\qquad $   or  $\qquad H(s)=e^{-0.01s^2}$

$$\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{1}{1+0.01 s^2} \, ds=0.999168$$

$$\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{-0.01s^2} \, ds=0.999167$$

```
Plot[{1/(1 + 0.01 x^2), E^(- 0.01 x^2)}, {x, -50, 50}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 1.2}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
P[n_, m_] := 3^n (2 Range[-m, m] + 1)
H[s_] := 1/(1 + 0.01 s^2)
beta[n_, t_, i_] := H[n^2 (t - i)]
a[t_] := Sum[Total[beta[n, t, #] & /@ P[n, 10]], {n, 5}]

Plot[a[t], {t, -50, 50}, Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> "Z=[-10,10]", 
 PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
P[n_, m_] := 3^n (2 Range[-m, m] + 1)
H[s_] := E^(- 0.01 s^2)
beta[n_, t_, i_] := H[n^2 (t - i)]
a[t_] := Sum[Total[beta[n, t, #] & /@ P[n, 10]], {n, 5}]

Quiet@Plot[a[t], {t, -50, 50}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotLabel -> "Z=[-10,10]", PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**Original Answer:**

Here is my attempt. But you can play with it.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
P[n_, m_] := 3^n (2 Range[-m, m] + 1)
H[s_] := UnitBox[s]
beta[n_, t_, i_] := H[n^2 (t - i)]
a[t_] := Sum[Total[beta[n, t, #] & /@ P[n, 10]], {n, 5}]

Plot[a[t], {t, -50, 50}, Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> "Z=[-10,10]", 
 PlotStyle -> Red, PlotPoints -> 100, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
P[n_, m_] := 3^n (2 Range[-m, m] + 1)
H[s_] := UnitBox[s]
beta[n_, t_, i_] := H[n^2 (t - i)]
a[t_] := Sum[Total[beta[n, t, #] & /@ P[n, 10]], {n, 5}]   

 Plot[a[t], {t, -50, 50}, Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> "Z=[-10,10]", 
 PlotStyle -> Red, PlotPoints -> 500, Exclusions -> True]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: The "H" function needs to be smooth whereas the unit box has jump ciscontinuities. But I wonder if it can be used to give a limit of approximations to a(t) that are smooth, since it is itself such a limit?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thank you very much for you answers. This responds exactly to my question. Now, from this plots, it is clear that  the function $a(t)$ is of oscillatory type and smooth. But it is not clear that it is not bounded!! Thank you again.

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci Thank you very much for your interesting response and I apologize for the delay for my intervention. Kind regards